# java get elements inside array but know arrayname in string

Tags: java

```
String[] strsub0={"out","err","in","console()"};
String[] strsub1={"print","println","append","close","flush"};
```

i want to get array elements and i know the name of the array.but i know aray name in String

```
int i=0; //this i get through a loop ,so i can't code strsub0 in my code.

String arrayname="strsub"+i;  //this is array name i want ,but it is a String.
```

//so i want get all elements inside array which name is strsub+i ;
//arrayname.length not return strsub0.length but i want it.

```
for(int z=0;z<arrayname.length;z++){  

   System.out.println(arrayname[z]);

}
```

Comment: What is high level requirement? Something like what you are asking is rarely ever needed

Comment: Try making it into array of arrays like: 
`String[][] a = {substr0, substr1,...}; for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) { /* your code */ }`

Comment: Do you know which arrays you will be using beforehand?

Comment: @geoand  may be.but i only have this solution .

Comment: It's the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You probably want to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You want an array of arrays.

```
String[][] strsub={{"out","err","in","console()"},
                   {"print","println","append","close","flush"};
```

Then you can get

```
String[] arr = strsub[i];
```

Comment: This was the only viable solution I could think of as well - that made any sense at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map whose key is what you want and whose value is the array. Like the following:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>(); //(assuming you have Java 7+ for the <> operator)
map.put("strsub0 ", new String[]{"out", "err", "in", "console()"});
map.put("strsub1 ", new String[]{"print", "println", "append", "close", "flush"});
```

Then retrieve the values like: `map.get(arrayname)[i]`. Of course you would have to check whether `map.get(arrayname)` actually exists or is `null`